# Trimming ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I used this command to trim the video:

"ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -to 00:06:49 -c copy out1.ts ffmpeg -ss 00:07:13 -i input.mp4 -c copy out2.ts ffmpeg -i 'concat:out1.ts|out2.ts' -c copy output3.mp4"

This command works, but it causes the video to freeze for about 1 second wherever I trim it. I have attached a video below to provide an example of the freeze frame issue.

example : https://jumpshare.com/v/r510dpNflKUFJEFXQXlP